# scanning file contents into a linked list

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I have a file which contains the information of employees(Name and their ID) of a company.
Sample file:

> Sailesh 160031158
>   John 160031145
>   Sam 160031499

I need to scan these contents into a linked list. If I know the number of employees(say 'x') present in the file, I can store them in a linked list using following code snippet:

```
struct node
{
    int id;
    char name[100];
    struct node *next;
}*start=NULL,*new,*prev;

void scan()
{
    fp=fopen("employee_info.c","r");
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    { 
        if(start==NULL)
        {
            new=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            start=new;
            fscanf(fp,"%s%d",new->name,&new->id);
            new->next=NULL;
            prev=new;
        }
        else
        {
            new=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            fscanf(fp,"%s%d",new->name,&new->id);
            new->next=NULL;
            prev->next=new;
            prev=new;
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I should be able to scan the details in the file into the linked list without knowing the no. of employees present('x').

Comment: What is the variable `x` and where it is defined? Why are you having global variables when they could as well be local (e.g. `new` and `prev`)? Why isn't there any indentation of the code (indentation makes it much easier to read)? Finally, and for your problem, [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) might come in handy. Pay close attention to what `scanf` ***returns***.

Comment: Use `fgets` and `sscanf` instead of `fscanf`.

Comment: this line: `void scan()` will cause the compiler to produce code for any number of parameters.  Suggest: `void scan( void )` which will cause compiler to produce code for zero/no parameters

Comment: using a variable named `new` is a very bad idea on compilers that can also compile `C++`.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `malloc()`, 1) do not cast the returned value.  the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer. 2) casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, like `fscanf()`, always check the returned value to assure it matches the number of actual inputs (parameter count) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C documentation, the method `fscanf()` has the following return value

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument
>   list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of
>   items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading
>   error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
>
> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while
>   reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). **And, if either
>   happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.**

So rather than your `for` loop, try putting the result of fscanf into a while loop and testing for the `EOF` return value. Something like this:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%s%d", new->name, &new->id) != EOF) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: `!= EOF` is not as good as `== 2`, since a return value of `1,0,EOF` are all a problem.